# Sequelize - Select on associated table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

**My problem:** 


I am creating an route which will return some informations about a group, it has an id, an user assigned and also has some documents. I just want to show how much documents exists, in SQL would be SELECT COUNT, but how can i do this in this in sequelize?

**My code:**

```
async list(req, res){
        const docGroups = await DocGroup.findAll({
            raw: true,
            include: [{
                  model: User,
                  as: 'userAssigned'
               },
               {
                  model: Document,
                  as: 'Document'
               }
            ]
        }).then(groups => {
            const result = groups.map(group => {
                return Object.assign(
                    {},
                    {
                        id: group.id,
                        name: group.name,
                        userAssinged: group['userAssigned.firstName'],
                        docAmount: // I want to put documents' count here

                    }   
                )

            })
            console.log(groups)    
        })
    }
```

**What is printed in console.log(groups):**

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'pleaseworks',
    createdAt: 2020-06-10T02:38:11.531Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-06-10T02:38:11.531Z,
    'userAssigned.id': 1,
    'userAssigned.firstName': 'Please',
    'userAssigned.lastName': 'Works',
    'userAssigned.email': 'pleaseworks@gmail.com',
    'userAssigned.password': '$2a$08$3BA4I4dsaQ3lsHy342344b5P41v5eHWjwqv6dve28nSdqbGvhsdS',
    'userAssigned.createdAt': 2020-06-10T02:37:29.062Z,
    'userAssigned.updatedAt': 2020-06-10T02:37:29.062Z,
    'userAssigned.groupId': null,
    'Document.id': 2,
    'Document.description': 'deowkdopewkdwe',
    'Document.content': 'odepodkewokodwe',
    'Document.groupId': 1,
    'Document.createdAt': 2020-06-10T02:43:46.005Z,
    'Document.updatedAt': 2020-06-10T02:43:46.005Z
  }
]
```

Comment: Show model association definotions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `DocGroup` has many `Document` try something like this:

```
{
  model: Document,
  attributes: [[sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('id')), 'docAmount']]
  as: 'Document'
}
```